# How to remove to space form the right site of the website in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have website in which i use bootstrap and new in css so there is space in right , want to remove that but some how can't do it , kindly help me . here the website link http://www.sabkideal.com/

and how to make mobile friendly website which display in google light browser  because when i run the site they give error and not show the website . Kindly help me out

Comment: `body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }`

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: how i add bootstrap code here

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="padding-top: 20px; margin-left: -10px;" class="container">
```

You have to remove margin

```
<div style="padding-top: 20px;" class="container">
```

Comment: if you see the site ui laying on left how to center this thanks

Comment: in which section and remove all container div margins @Abhishek bhatnagar

Comment: #footer div ul, #footer h3 {
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

Answer (score 0):

well it entirely depends on what sort of content / html element you are working with. 
This [link](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block) has numerous solutions to your problem. Out of all of the solutions proposed in this link, solution 1 is my personal recommendation.

If you are working with a `<p>` element, which I dont think you are, you can use the CSS white space property.

If you working with the inner text of an element and are open not using CSS to fix this problem, then I would recommend using JS to clean up for the text for display.